# Creating a CI/CD pipeline using gitlab with Airflow composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, airflow, cicd

I have stored the dag script on gitlab and want to build a CI/CD pipeline on it. I am using GCP Airflow composer how
Will i able to achieve it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is a bit vague and could use a bit more detail.  Check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to ask a good question and increase the chances you'll get the response you need.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but as i have linked other post i thought it's clear. But now i  have updated the question.